# How do you add a dropdown button inside a linked list group item in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to add a dropdown button on the right of a linked `.list-group-item`. I've tried the following, but it looks like an extra `<a class="list-group-item" href="#">` is being insert (by Javascript?) and the dropdown does not work. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bsm3o76u/). I need the `a` tag, so I can't use an onclick.

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
    some text

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle pull-right" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </a>
</ul>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7. Thanks!

Comment: is there any reason you need to use li's instead of select/option?

Comment: Do you mean for the dropdown? The [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#dropdowns) uses li's.

Answer (score 0):

So what I've done, I have changed the link to be li, changed the class to be btn-group in the snippet below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      some text
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
     </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks close, but I need the list-group-item to be a clickable link. Any idea how to keep it an `a`?